# done() method on Promises/A+ specification usage in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

[Here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress) it is recommended to end promises chain with done methods for the error be re-thrown:

> The Golden Rule of done vs. then usage is: either return your promise
>   to someone else, or if the chain ends with you, call done to terminate
>   it. Terminating with catch is not sufficient because the catch handler
>   may itself throw an error.

Is it applied to AngularJs? I've looked and there is seems to be no such method in the framework.

**UPDATE:**

I've taken look at the code and found the following:

```
try {
    if (isFunction(fn)) {
        promise.resolve(fn(state.value));
    } else if (state.status === 1) {
        promise.resolve(state.value);
    } else {
        promise.reject(state.value);
    }
} catch (e) {
    promise.reject(e);
    exceptionHandler(e);
}

window.onerror = function(e) {
    // doesn't come here
}
```

So basically angular additionally logs the error from the promise handler in `exceptionHandler(e);` so it doesn't go unnoticed. If needed, default `exceptionHandler`'s behaviour can be over-ridden as explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `done()` method on Promises/A+ specification

Notice that Promises does only specify `then`, it says nothing about `done`.

> [`Q` recommends](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress) to… What about usage in Angular?

`Q` is not [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)! There is no `done` method on Angular's promise implementation, so I would recommend not to use it.

The golden rules of `Q` do not apply to Angular, they have largely different features.

---

Promises are asynchronous, so you cannot use a `try catch` statement around the callbacks. `done` is used for throwing an unrecoverable, uncatchable to the environment (so [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) or [`process.onuncaughtexception`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) would be called).

If you want to catch exceptions, you should use the `catch` method with a callback:

```
$q.reject(new Error()).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("does catch an error"); 
});
```

To catch unhandled rejections (at the end of your promise chains), you also can use [`$exceptionHandler`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24exceptionHandler).

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to catch the error thrown inside `catch` handler like I showed in my update? And since angular's `$exceptionHandler` catches errors thrown inside promises (which are according to the spec get consumed within promises), the error will not go unnoticed, right?

Comment: Yeah, my example is invalid, sorry, didn't think it through. The idea is that if an exception occurs inside of a callback `c` here `.catch(c)`, without `done()` this exception will not be reported in a non angular app according to the docs of `Q` and will go unnoticed, right?

Comment: @Maximus: Yes, it would just reject the returned promise with it. Which might or might not be unnoticed (only in the end of a promise chain).

Comment: right, so in angular world it will always be noticed (no done() method required) because it's being evaluated inside `digest` loop and `$exceptionHandler` can pick it up?

Comment: Not sure, I wouldn't think so, but I don't know Angular that well. Surely you can try it out?

Comment: checked source code, please see my update, maybe you'll have anything to comment. I've also removed the wrong example with `try...catch`.

Comment: "*doesn't do anything else to provide means to handle it*" doesn't seem accurate - if you want to handle it, you can both use `exceptionHandler` and `.catch()` on the rejection apparently.

Comment: yeah, you're right, I'll remove that line. I can override default `exceptionHandler` to re-throw if needed as explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler). I wouldn't normally use second `catch()` as I wouldn't normally expect a rejection in a `failure` callback.

Comment: Could you update your answer with what I've found so that I can accept it? Or maybe I should move my update into an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Angular use $q which is :

> an implementation of promises/deferred objects inspired by Kris Kowal's Q.

You need to use [the Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#!) provided in angular documentation : .finally(), .then(), and .catch().

Angular describe such difference quite well :

> Q has many more features than $q, but that comes at a cost of bytes. $q is tiny, but contains all the important functionality needed for common async tasks.

So looks like there is no .done() in $q.

Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to sebastienbarbier's answer, the $q angular service is also tied into the $digest cycle (that angular runs internally) and which (for $q) performs the function of .done() in Kris Kowal's Q.

This can catch you out in tests, where a $scope.digest() ensures that the promises are fully resolved.